# Can we pass database name in a SQL query as parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

Consider the following queries, where only database name differs (on same server)

```
Select * from sampledev.dbo.Sample
Select * from sampleqa.dbo.Sample
```

The above queries are part of a procedure. Every time I have to run the procedure, I have to make sure it references the correct database (and do rename, if it is not).

I want to pass the database name as a parameter to the stored procedure. The question is, is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Why not just put the same SPR in both dbs, and include a parameter that tells the code which Select to use?

Comment: because dbs can change, and i have this repetition at lot many places.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using `sp_executesql`

```
DECLARE @Database   NVARCHAR(255),
        @Query      NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Database = 'Database'
SET @Query = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @Database + '.dbo.Table'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection.  It would be better to use paramaters.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Is it possible without dynamic query?

Comment: @Vulcronos how? your link does not show the database name as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as: ?

```
CREATE PROC GetData
(
    @DatabaseName VARCHAR(255)
)
AS
BEGIN

IF @DatabaseName = 'sampledev'
    SELECT * FROM sampledev.dbo.Sample
ELSE IF @DatabaseName = 'sampleqa'
    SELECT * FROM sampleqa.dbo.Sample

END
```

**Use:**

***exec GetData 'sampledev'***

> Results
>
> ---
>
> dev data
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

***exec GetData 'sampleqa'***

> Results
>
> ---
>
> qa data
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

Comment: if else ladder is difficult to maintain. I have many databases, and this repetition is at many places also.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the leading [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014429/6844481) but without SQL injection vulnerability.

First you must query the `sys.databases` in order to be sure to get the real Database name while not counting on the users text:

```
SELECT @Database = [name]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = @Database;
```

Now perform the query using `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(200);
SET @Query =  N'SELECT * FROM '  + @DBName + '.dbo.sample';
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

---

Full Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyScheme].[MyStoredProcedure] 
(
    @DBName sysname
)

AS
BEGIN
    
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    SELECT @DBName = [name]
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE [name] = @DBName;

    DECLARE @Query nvarchar(200);
    SET @Query =  N'SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.sample';
    EXEC sp_executesql @Query

END
GO
```

---

Or even a simpler version using QUOTENAME(...) to prevent SQL injection.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyScheme].[MyStoredProcedure] 
(
    @DBName sysname
)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max);
    SET @Query =  N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.dbo.sample';
    EXEC sp_executesql @Query

END
GO
```